# vim can not interact with system clipboards / Ubuntu

Tags: vim, clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded Ubuntu in the Win 10 app store, installed vim, vim-gnome, opened + clipboard and + xterm_clipboard while viewing vim

But I vim: reg when there is no + or * clipboard, it can not be copied to the system clipboard

Comment: File a bug report: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues

Comment: The problem has been solved, this is the link：https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/892

Comment: Could you please post an answer that summarises the solution for other readers?

Answer (score 1):

Problem Description: I downloaded Ubuntu in the Win 10 App Store, installed vim, vim-gnome, opened the + clipboard and + xterm_clipboard while browsing vim

But I vim: reg when there is no + clipboard or * clipboard, it can not be copied to the system clipboard

The cause of the problem: Ubuntu downloaded from the Win 10 App Store is without a GUI and needs to be installed with VcXarv

Solution: For those who want to go the X server route, let me leave my notes here.

1. Install VcXsrv (I found that Xing is outdated on sourceforge and
   the new version is donationware)
2. If it starts after installing, stop it
3. Start it using XLaunch (search in the start menu), go with all the
   defaults (ensure the clipboard options are checked)
4. At the end, save the configuration to a file (use that to start it
   from now on) Put export DISPLAY = localhost: 0.0 in your .bashrc in
   bash for Windows (and run the command in any open bash windows). The
   reason I said say localhost is that this makes SSH X forwarding
   work, see below.
5. Ensure vim is installed using clipboard support. Vim --version |
   grep clipboard should say + clipboard, not -clipboard. Also if you
   run the ex command: echo has ('clipboard') in vim and it says 0 it
   does not have clipboard support compiled in. If you do not have
   clipboard support, install the vim-gtk package (apt-get install
   vim-gtk).
6. It should now work
7. As a bonus you should now be able to copy from and to your Windows
   clipboard from a remote machine by using SSH X forwarding (ssh -X
   ...). You can use xclip on the remote machine or if you use vim
   there you will again need to make sure the clipboard option is
   compiled into vim (eg install vim-gtk). You can probably also
   configure PuTTY to use your local X server in case you prefer using
   that for remote connections.

(The solution comes from robbiev's comment, this is the link: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/892)